# Efficient way of finding the intersections between polynomial curves?

Tags: python, numpy

The fitting by `np.polyfit()` returns me several polynomial expressions. I then plot the polynomial curves with `matplotlib`:

```
y_fit = np.arange(min(y), max(y), .1) # use more points for a smoother plot
x_fit = p[0](y_fit)
axes.plot(x_fit, y_fit, '-', color='green')
```

What I get is this

[image: Polynomial Curves]

They are actually the boundaries of a passage. **I expect to see a closed blue polygon inside the green closed polygon.** Using human intelligence, it is quite clear how to intersect them and remove the extra parts.

A simple and brutal method that I **have tried** is to solve **pairwise** coupled non-linear equation with `fsolve()`. **However**, this is quite infeasible, as I have a lot of polynomial curves, and thus solving them pairwise is too expensive. Also, it is clear that not all the intersections are important. *(some intersections even hardly make sense!)*

So is it possible for me to do this (get the **crucial** intersections **only**) **efficiently**?

Answer (score 4):

You can find intersections of polynomial curves by finding roots:

```
import numpy as np

# fake data
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 20)
y1 = np.cos(x)
y2 = np.sin(x)

# polynomial fits
p1 = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x, y1, 3)
p2 = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x, y2, 3)

# find roots
x_0 = (p1 - p2).roots()
print(x_0)

# select roots in specific range only
x_0 = x_0[(x_0 > 0) & (x_0 < 4)]

# plot
xx = np.linspace(0, 4, 2000)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y1, 'b.', x, y2, 'g.')
plt.plot(xx, p1(xx), xx, p2(xx))
plt.plot(x_0, p1(x_0), 'ko')
plt.show()
```

For polynomials obtained via `np.polyfit`, use `np.roots`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this can be done by solving the polynomial, but for my case, you will have to solve *every pair* right? That would be a disaster.